# Proximity Sensor to change button Color

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an app that the color of the buttons change with the proximity sensor.

I don't know quite how to change it on the `onSensorChanged` part. Must I have to import Color and implement different color states? I'm a bit confused.

Here's my code:

```
public class MainProxmityActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

Button proximidade;
SensorManager Sm;
Sensor ProxSensor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_proxmity);

    Sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService (SENSOR_SERVICE);
    ProxSensor = Sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    proximidade = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_proximidade);

    Sm.registerListener(this, ProxSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_proxmity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    proximidade.setBackgroundColor(getTitleColor("bd4c31"));
}

}
```

Hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 2):

Android devices have a bunch of sensors, so the onSensorChanged() code typically has a switch statement to select the sensor(s) of interest. In particular, the proximity sensor returns a float value that denotes proximity (e.g., < 1.0 is "close" if the sensor's max range is 5.0). Try something like this:

```
int mColor;
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
    case Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY:
        if (event.values[0] < 1.0f) {
            if (mColor != Color.GREEN) {
                mColor = Color.GREEN;
                proximidade.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (mColor != Color.WHITE) {
                mColor = Color.WHITE;
                proximidade.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Remember to register a listener to your proximity sensor in your onStart() code with something like this:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(mViewWithSensorListener, s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
```

Also unregister the listener to your proximity sensor in your onStop() code with something like this:

```
mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mViewWithSensorListener);
```

Comment: Hi @gregS
Thanks for your contribution in helping me. Very appreceated.

I have a question related to what you said  about onStart() and onStop() codes. Does that relates to the onSensorChanged() and onAccuracyChanged(), respectively? I´ve tryed to do it as you said but it doesn't seem to work althought there are no errors.

here is the code :

Comment: public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
  Sm.unregisterListener(mViewWithSensorListener);}

 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
  
  Sm.registerListener(mViewWithSensorListener, 


is this the way you register and unresgister the listener?

Comment: Because the accuracy of your device's proximity sensor won't change, there's no point in overriding onAccuracyChanged() for it. On the other hand, onAccuracyChanged() is frequently used for location sensors. I hope that helps.

Comment: Hey gregS. thanx for taking the time in answering me. Look. i get an error on 'event' in the code you gave me. would you care to explain me why this is happening?

Comment: Hey! I got it working. I realized that my Samsung Galaxy Tab GT P1000 didnt have a proximity sensor. I've tried it in my phone Galaxy mini and it worked. Thanx for the tips man. Apreceated!